# nsmutablearray addobject adding object.text twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Using addObject is adding the object twice

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"LOG1 %@", object.text);
        [appdelegate.mutarray addObject:object.text];
        NSLog(@"LOG2 %@", appdelegate.mutarray);
```

Log1 returns: LOG1 value
Log2 returns: LOG2 (
    "value",
    "value"
)

why is it adding in twice? removeObject removes both can i remove just one

Comment: Log the array just before adding the object.

Comment: Need to see the code where you fetch the object, and the code where you delete the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your first time added your value to NSMutableArray through without remove value from the NSMutableArray going add often. that so far it be adding concurrent duplicate value. before adding new value remove your entire array.

```
 if(appdelegate.mutarray.count!=0)
 [appdelegate.mutarray removeAllObject];

 [appdelegate.mutarray addObject:object.text];
```

Comment: removeAllObjects works [doesnt duplicate and only outputs one value] but i don't want to remove all because i want to keep the other favorites.. I tried [appdelegate.mutarray removeObject:object.text]; but only allows for one favorite

Comment: use index based to remove like removeObjectAtIndex

Comment: so apparently i had it added somewhere earlier too. thanks thou